# Бинарное дерево C++

Tags: дерево, бинарное-дерево, c++

У меня есть входной файл

```
0 0 7
7 0 25
7 1 12
25 0 18
25 1 3
18 0 6
12 0 22
12 1 8
```

По этому файлу строится бинарное дерево. Первая цифра обозначает значение родителя, если она равна 0, то это корень. Вторая цифра говорит будет новый элемент справа или слева (0 или 1). Третий символ это значение нового узла. 
Метод добавления элемента

```
void add(ONode *&tree, int val, int left = NULL) {
    if(tree == NULL) {
        tree = new ONode;
        tree->val = val;
        tree->left = tree->right = NULL;
    }
    else {
        (left == 1) ? add(tree->right, val) : add(tree->left, val);
    }
}
```

И само добавление

```
while(!feof(input)) {
    int p, l, v;
    fscanf(input, "%d %d %d", &p, &l, &v);
    if(p == 0) add(a, v);
    else {
        ONode *t = NULL;
        t = search(a, p);
        add(t, v, l);
    }
}
```

Но всё рушится когда пытаюсь добавить 18 в дерево, с выводом

> Первый этап обработки исключения по адресу 0x00CF3E21 в ConsoleApplication12.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFDFDFE01.
>   Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00CF3E21 в ConsoleApplication12.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFDFDFE01.

в чём может быть дело ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: проблема была в функции `search`.

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что нужно сделать это поставить брекпоинт и запустить отладчик (так найдётся место на котором вылет...)

1. почему вы после создания потомка
       (7-0-25 или 7-1-12) у родителя (7)
       не меняете адреса `left` и `right`?
       (они так и остаются равные "0" )
2. как после выше описанного сможет
       отработать функция search? Да и ещё
       вернуть "что-то" куда потом вставить
       val

вот вам и ошибка доступа...